# Inteiro muito grande não funciona

Tags: c, tipagem, inteiros

Meu código está assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long int L, N;
    scanf("%lu%lu", &L, &N);

    printf("%lu\n", (L-(N-1))*(L-(N-1)) + (N-1));

    return 0;
}
```

Quando o caso de teste tem números baixos, o programa funciona. Porém, quando os números estão além da capacidade do `unsigned long int`, com entradas como 1.000.000 e 9 (a resposta correta seria 999984000072) o programa dá a resposta errada.

Como posso operar com inteiros maiores?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se tiveres uma implementacao de C99, podes experimentar `unsigned long long`. Este tipo tem que existir, mas pode nao ser maior que `unsigned long` --- e, portanto, pode nao te resolver o problema.

Verifica com, por exemplo `sizeof (unsigned long) == sizeof (unsigned long long)`

Se poderes usar este tipo, lembra-te de usar `"%llu"` tanto nos printfs como nos scanfs.

Nesse caso, ou usas uma biblioteca para numeros grandes ou fazes a tua versao de multiplicacao de numeros como aprendeste na escola primaria (um projecto muito interessante).

Comment: ou ainda ... *faz batota: `sprintf(cmd, "echo 'n=%lu; l=%lu; print (l-(n-1))*(l-(n-1))+(n-1)' | python", n, l); system(cmd);`*

Comment: Oh! So mais uma coisa. As strings de conversao para `unsigned long long` usam `%llu` tanto no printf como no scanf.

Answer (score 6):

Utilize o tipo [`unsigned long long`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=vs-2019) e seja feliz.